# parallax scrolling pages arranged oddly

Tags: html, css, parallax

I want the about div to show up BELOW the
[full screen home card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyGnR.png)

I'm having troubles getting it to show like it should.

my html code has both divs in the "right" order and when i look it up online, i couldn't find any solutions.

```
<body>
    <div class="homeCard">
        <div class="homeCardTitle">
            <h1>Robin Riezebos</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aboutCard">
        <div class="aboutCardText">
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

my css is either missing something or I did something completely wrong but I can't seem to find out what it is so please help...

index.css

```
.homeCard {
    background-image: url("images/helicopter-in-sky-2.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
}

.homeCardTitle {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
.aboutCard {
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    color: white;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain or give us an image/example of exactly what you want it to look like?

Comment: as the site was, there was a blank space above the parallax background div, with my about text hidden behind the picture.
What I wanted was my about "Card" to lay atop the parallax  background and below the fullscreen home "Card".

I've fixed it myself and you can see the WIP of the website at http://robinriezebos.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Please change your css like below, i think the problem was with position fixed, if you want to get your background image rendered fully please respective pixels of height.

```
.homeCard {
            background-image: url("images/helicopter-in-sky-2.jpg");
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        .homeCardTitle {
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
        }

        .aboutCard {
            background-color: #1F1F1F;
            color: white;
            height: 500px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by bugging around in my css.
Turns out in stead of `position: fixed;` I should have used `background-attachment: fixed;` and remove `position` all-together.

this is my own fixed code:

```
.homeCard {
    background-image: url("images/helicopter-in-sky-2.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    float: left;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
}

.homeCardTitle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -90px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
.aboutCard {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
    color: white;
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```